# How can I change the size and frequency of villages in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am running Java 1.20.1 on MacOS, and am curious as to how to change the world generation settings to affect the size and frequency of villages. I am completely new to JSON files and all that, and so a lot of tutorials I have seen have presupposed some knowledge which I clearly don't have!

Which specific file directories should I be looking into to change these things?